I am trying to Determine Wire Size and Capacity
This is regarding Aluminum wire with the following writing on it;
ALCAN CALIF 4CDRS6AL TYPE SE CABLE STYLE SER TYPE XHHW CONDUCTORS 300 VOLTS

Off hand from not an expert, 6 gauge and should be safe for 40 amp circuits.  There might be uses that higher amps would be allowed.

I was afraid that was the case. It has had a 70amp breaker on it since I moved into my house 32 years ago. It feeds a detached garage subpanel that is 60' away.

This is why we need the experts, but 70 might be too much.  Feeder circuits have a bit different allowances than house/branch circuits.


ALCAN CALIF - Manufacturer
4CDRS - 4 conductors, which is good - hot, hot, neutral, ground
6AL - 6 AWG aluminum - OK for 50A max.
TYPE SE CABLE STYLE SER TYPE - Type of cable - "Service Entrance"
XHHW CONDUCTORS - Type of wires - this is standard.
300 VOLTS - Insulation level - this is standard.

If used as actual service entrance cable, this would be good for 60A, but not when feeding a subpanel. If thete are no other issues, the safe thing to do is to replace the 70A breaker with a 50A breaker.
If you think you need more power, start a new question with:

A picture of the subpanel
A description of the current and planned loads


Wow, that is great knowledge, Thank you. I am replacing my 200 amp Zinsco Main with a 200 amp Siemens and wanted to be correct on the Breaker Sizes. The Subpanel is for lights, plugs, Jacuzzi Tub Pump, an attic fan and a bath fan.

@KevinRoton   Check what the pump needs.  That is probably the biggest power hog.   The rest might might use a 20 amp circuit, depending on what the plugs are used for, the odd use vacuum or a machine shop.

Downvoter care to explain what I did wrong?

If you’re going to explain how to interpret wire markings, you should mention that the type/temperature rating (XHHW) matters - do not just dismiss it as “standard”. True in the case of aluminum 75C rating is the only one anybody uses, but in general you find the ampacity rating in a chart by looking for the intersection of metal (Cu/Al), wire type, and size - not just metal and size.
